# Examples of contractions between functional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Define $\mathcal{F}$ as the following set of continuous functions:

$$ \mathcal{F} := \left\{ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(\cdot) \  \text{contin.}, \ f(x) \in K(x) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ K(x) \neq \varnothing \ \text{compact, } K(\cdot)  \ \text{contin.}  \right\} $$

I am looking for examples of contractions operator $\mathcal{C}: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: I don't understand what $K$ is. From the way you have set it up it is a map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{A \subset \mathbb{R}: A$ is compact $\}$. What does it mean for such a function to be continuous?

Comment: I mean that $K: \mathbb{R} \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous, compact-valued set-valued mapping.

Comment: What topology do you endow the set of compact sets with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $C:F\to F$ such that $C(f)=\frac{1}{2}f$, then $\|C(f)-C(g)\|=\|\frac{1}{2}(f-g)\|\lt\|f-g\|$, contraction?

Comment: I'd suggest maybe an integral operator or something, but there are no assumptions about integration or differentiation in the set $F$.

Comment: I am not sure about $C[f(\cdot)] := \frac{1}{2} f(\cdot)$. In fact, it can be that - for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ - $f(x) \in K(x)$ while $\frac{1}{2} f(x) \notin K(x)$.

Comment: is that because (as a hypothetical example) let $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $K=[2,3]$ then let $f(x)=5/2\in K$, but $\frac{1}{2}f=5/4$ which is not in $K$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Probably I can think of a certain function in $\mathcal{F}$ an try to "reduce the distance" from it.

Comment: Wouldn't you need more restrictions on $K$, since $K$ is an arbitrary compact set, so if you give a contraction map, we can probably come up with a counter example, that so to say makes $f$ "fall out" of $K$?

Comment: Well, I want to find examples of $\mathcal{C}$'s such that $f$ does not fall out.

Comment: Definitely, I was wondering if you constructed this problem yourself or is it homework?

Comment: Also does $C$ need to be linear?

Comment: No, $\mathcal{C}$ may be non-linear.

Comment: What if, for some fixed $g(\cdot) \in \mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{C}[ f(\cdot) ] := g(\cdot)$ for all $f(\cdot) \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Then you would have:
$\|C(f)-C(h)\|=\|g-g\|=\|0\|=0\lt\|f-h\|$, so this seems like a good candidate, but not a very interesting one.